# Investigate other values of $R(m, n)$, observing patterns, making conjectures, and constructing proofs

Tags: combinatorics

In an array of dots, how many can be colored red without forming a red rectangle?
• We use rectangular arrays of dots, and consider only those rectangles with horizontal and vertical
sides. A dot-rectangle is called “red” if its four corners are red. (Other dots can be of any color.)
For whole numbers $m, n,$  define $R(m, n)$ to be the largest number of dots in an m ×n
array that can be colored red without making a red rectangle.
For instance, in a  $3\times 3$  array an L-shaped arrangement of 5 red dots contains no
red rectangle. Therefore $R(3,3)\ge 5$  But 5 is not maximal: there is a rectangle-free
arrangement of 6 red dots, proving that $(3,3)\ge 6$  After some work I managed to
prove:
Every arrangement of 7 red dots in a  $3\times 3$  array must include a red rectangle.
This shows that $R(3,3)=6$

**Question**: Investigate other values of $R(m, n)$, observing patterns, making conjectures, and
constructing proofs

Comment: This may be a very hard problem. Do you know about Ramsey theory? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory